# SimpleGui inputs into a variable

Tags: python, codeskulptor

On simplegui I want there to be an input box called login_gui that puts the data from the input into the variable login_variable, not into a defined function.

```
import simplegui
frame = simplegui.create_frame("screen", 500, 500)
login_gui = frame.add_input("Login?", login_variable, 20)
 ..something with login_variable
```

Is there any way to do this, or is it only with defined functions that this works?

Comment: Do you specifically need a simplegui solution, or are you open to other toolkits?

Comment: Anything works, it's just CodeSkulptor has other turorials and such like

Comment: @L0neGamer: I know I'm a bit late, but were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know.  But using tkinter or pyside is very simple and then you have all options avaliable.

updated with an example

Basically pyside is better, but tkinter works out of the box. If you just want a simple gui, just use tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

def go():
    print E1.get()
top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.pack()
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.pack()

But = Button(top, text="go", command=go)
But.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question is specifically about how to do something with SimpleGui. Suggesting alternate toolkits isn't very helpful.

Comment: I disagree.  The asker of the question might not know that other and potential better tools are avaliable.  I would be happy if someone pointed me to a better tool.  I use Python because it's a better tool that Windows bat files. ..

Comment: @Cyrex could you provide links to the documentation of both? I can't find the Tkinter one and I don't fully understand the Pyside one yet

Comment: Added tkinter example

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the input string by calling the `get_text()` method of the variable that is assigned to the input field.

> login_variable = login_gui.get_text()

Please note that you will still have to define an input handler function somewhere, but can leave it blank (and do not name it `login_variable` as you're using it to store the input text)

```
def input_handler(input):
     pass

login_gui = frame.add_input("Login?", input_handler, 20)
```

Source: SimpleGui [documentation](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#get_text).

Answer (score 0):

you can just call the box with name and use it

> `name = enterbox("Enter the company name:", "Name")
>   msgbox("Hello " + name)         # will show what you entered`